# How can I play with a friend in another city?

Tags: ps3, fifa-13

So how can I play with a friend on the same team against another friend?

We'll all be logging in on different machines in different cities!

Does FIFA 13 even allow co-operative play?

Comment: Not really aware of how FiFA works, but I've never heard of any game that allows online multiplayer, co-operative or versus, that changes what works depending on native cities lived in by players.

Comment: The game almost certainly doesn't even have a way of knowing where you are located with any accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware you can only play team vs team, not together in the same team. That is only possible when both play on the same device.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pro club and play on the same team, but that will only allow you to control your individual players.  Co-op for online play only works with two players on the same console.